# mongoose make sure document is unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I know I can add unique fields in schemas, and using some library (e.g. `mongoose-unique-validator`) I can validate that no two documents have the same value for that field.

However, how can I ensure that the combination of *all* fields is unique?

E.g. this should be allowed:

```
new Model({name: 'foo', prop: 'bar'})
new Model({name: 'qux', prop: 'bar'})
new Model({name: 'foo', prop: 'qux'})
```

but this should not

```
new Model({name: 'foo', prop: 'bar'})
new Model({name: 'qux', prop: 'baz'})
new Model({name: 'foo', prop: 'bar'})
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer I have provided below?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I actually have no memory of this ^^ project, so I'm assuming after I asked the question the answer stopped being interesting to me. I probably haven't tested your answer.

Comment: Okay but you should accept the answer. And if you will get any issue at the time of testing you can reach to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set compound index... You can try this

```
schema.index({ "name": 1, "prop": 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is other option than checking if any document exists for each property in checked object.

```
async function hasAllProperitiesUnique(doc, cb){
    var queries = [];
    for (const v in doc) {
        queries.push(Model.count({v:doc[v]}));
    }
    return Promise.all(queries).then(res=>res.reduce((p,c)=>p+c,0))===0;
}
```